# Android: Error cannot find symbol NotificationCompat.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm following android's documentation on creating a custom notification for media playback controls. I read that it was recommended to set the style of the notification to DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle, however this gives me the following compilation error.

`error: cannot find symbol class DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle`

I'm importing `DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle` from `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`. When I try and use `DecoratedCustomViewStyle`, my media playback buttons in my notification do not work. But when I exclude setting the style, then my buttons work but the notification isn't decorated with the large icon and title.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. I had to import from `android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat` instead of `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`.

Comment: Thank you, I have been cleaning and restarting the project quite long time before have found this answer :)

Answer (score 15):

**This worked for me**
**rather**

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
```

***instead of*** `android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat` ***OR*** `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`

Answer (score 6):

I have been getting this error for a npm package I use (/@aws-amplify/pushnotification) when assembling release build (`./gradlew assembleRelease`) in a react-native project.

Resolved with Jetifier, which can be done by:

`yarn add jetifier --dev` or `npm install jetifier --save-dev`

Then adding these to scripts in package.json:

```
  "postinstall": "jetify",
  "jetify": "npx jetify"
```

Then run `yarn run jetifier` or `npm run jetifier`

`./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease` and build is successful. I assume androidx related issue.